# Flash Object Not Working in Angular UI Bootstrap modal in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to embed flash object inside angular ui modal and it's not working in Firefox but it is working in chrome. I've been working on these for the last 2 days and still can't find an answer. Using `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` solves the problem but i found that there are some problems using `opaque` in terms of keyboard events and this is not an option for me.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCOSdoP6vYbsJS9VXucr?p=preview) is the example code.

Comment: Removed noise from the question and improved formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution!

I added this in css.

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
    transform: none;
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Read [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @HarshalPatil OP doesn't wanted to give further information about the issue. He found a solution for his problem and answered his own question.

Comment: @Ravimallya You are using bootstrap so you know the things. What about beginner? Keep in mind that your answer is simple and clear. So anyone can understand by just overlook

Comment: Oh.. common man! Neither I didn't answer the question nor edited the answer. The OP itself answered his question, and I gave help link because you asked the OP to edit the question to include more details rather than answering.